# Is migration to Stack Overflow blocked?

Tags: discussion, migration

Recently, I have seen a couple of posts that I think were supposed to be migrated to SO, but weren't. Community locks them like it would for migrated questions and then almost immediately unlocks them. One example is https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/727041/revisions. The [10k tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) doesn't show anything odd.

Comment: That does sound like a bug. [The post timeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/727041/timeline) has a bit more info for mods, and I see 5 votes to migrate to SO, so I don't understand why it would fail.

Comment: My only guess at this point is that the asker is/was Question-blocked on SO. Just a guess!

Comment: @JeffSchaller that might be it. In the meantime I found the other post where I saw this happening: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726935/why-this-program-can-not-read-text-file-in-struct

Comment: If I'm right, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276407/307535 has some background. It might instead be tags? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318476/307535 ... but probably not, given the tags on these two questions.

Comment: More canonical reference on failed migrations: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/307535

Comment: The latter has a detailed flowchart which recommends *not* migrating questions with good answers unless they are at risk of deletion. That’s a criterion which we tend not to apply; I’ve had a few answers migrated to SO (with their parent question) after a few days, on questions which wouldn’t have warranted deletion here. (I don’t mind particularly, it always means more rep on SO…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause, IMHO, is that the OP's are/were question-blocked on SO. [The FAQ on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/307535) says, in part, regarding blocked migrations:

> What causes a migration to be blocked and what happens after?

> - The user is question-banned or suspended on the destination site, or is rate-limited due to question quality and the migration would cause them to exceed the rate limit

> - The question does not use any tags that exist on the destination site, with three exceptions ...

> - The question was cross-posted onto the other site (unless a moderator migrates)

[Question 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727041/i-want-to-compile-this-libelfin-library-file-under-windows-so-that-i-can-develop):

- had tags: [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux), [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows) -- both available on SO
- does not appear to have been cross-posted (at this point, and that's visible to me)
- the user does not appear to be suspended on SO (at this time)
- the user only has one question on SO from Nov 17th, making a rate-limit unlikely

... making a question-ban the most likely reason for this migration failure.

[Question 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726935/why-this-program-can-not-read-text-file-in-struct):

- had tags: [c](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c), read -- of which "c" is available on SO
- does not appear to have been cross-posted (at this point, and that's visible to me)
- the user does not appear to be suspended on SO (at this time)
- the [user's newest SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19475575/anup-adhikari?tab=questions&sort=newest) was over 4 months ago, making a rate-limit unlikely

... making a question-ban the most likely reason for this migration failure.

I can't say definitively, since I can't see how many deleted questions each user has, so this is just my best guess with what I can see. There may be other rate-limiting activities going on that I can't see, or cross-posted questions that are now deleted, that could also explain it.